# Unable to import module in Rascal project

Tags: module, rascal

I created a test project and added the following module as reference https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal-OFG. But when I tried to check it using the terminal. I'm getting the following error.

|prompt:///|(0,32,<1,0>,<1,32>): Could not import module lang::ofg::ast::Java2OFG: can not find in search path
Advice: |http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Errors/Static/ModuleImport/ModuleImport.html|

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

watch out for which project the terminal is active. If you:

1. first select the project your code is in, in the navigator by clicking on the project name
2. then start a Rascal console repl
3. you will see in the top of the console view the name of your project
4. this means the search path for the repl is set to the project and the interpret can find the files.